# Ionic App, Typescript Error Cannot find name 'RequestMode'

Tags: angular, ionic2, servicestack, ionic3

I have problem in my ionic app, after some updates in ionic & angular servicestack give me errors like the below

> Typescript Error Cannot find name 'RequestMode'.
>   node_modules/servicestack-client/src/index.d.ts

```
oneWayBaseUrl: string;
mode: RequestMode;
credentials: RequestCredentials;
```

> Typescript Error Cannot find name 'RequestCredentials'.
>   node_modules/servicestack-client/src/index.d.ts

```
mode: RequestMode;
credentials: RequestCredentials;
headers: Headers;
```

my ionic, angular and pc info

```
Typescript : 2.4.2
Ionic Framework: 3.1.1
Ionic App Scripts: 1.3.4
Angular Core: 4.0.2
Angular Compiler CLI: 4.0.2
Node: 6.10.0
OS Platform: macOS Sierra
Navigator Platform: MacIntel
User Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36
```

tsconfig.json file

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": ["dom","es2015"],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "typings/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "atom": {
    "rewriteTsconfig": false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the [tsconfig.json that servicestack-client was built with](https://github.com/ServiceStack/servicestack-client/blob/master/tsconfig.json) using the latest [v2.4.2 of typescript](https://github.com/ServiceStack/servicestack-client/blob/master/package.json#L51) where it references the W3C fetch types in TypeScript's built-in [lib.dom.d.ts](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.dom.d.ts), so if you're referencing lib `dom` you'll have access to these missing types.

Not sure what the issue is with your project but I'd look into anything that can cause type definition conflicts like any `typings/*` that may cause conflicts.